# Re-fetching data automatically when Database values changes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-redux

Inside my react App, i have a component that shows a list of data fetched from my database.
Now i would like to refresh my component every "X" seconds so if the database values have changed, my component will show also those new values.
Here's my code...

```
const SingleBet = () => {

 const { data } =  useGetAllBetsQuery() //REDUX FETCH

  return (
    
    <Paper sx={{marginTop:"10px", background:"white"}}>
        <Grid container xs={12} sx={{display:"flex", flexDirection:"row", height:"50px"}}>
            //ITEMS NO NEEDED
        </Grid>
        {data.map((data, index) => {
           return (
            <Paper sx={sxPaperList} key={index}>
                <Grid container rowSpacing={2} sx={sxGridContainer}>
                    <Grid item xs={4} >
                        {data.ImportoG1 > 0 ? (
                            <Typography variant="h6" sx={sxTypographyNames}>{data.Giocatore1}
                            <img src={star} alt="little_star" height="15"/></Typography>
                        ) : (
                            <Typography variant="h6" sx={sxTypographyNames}>
                             {data.Giocatore1}       
                            </Typography>
                        )}
                    //OTHER THINGS LIKE THIS
                </Grid>            
            </Paper>
           )
        })}
    </Paper>
  )
}
```

How u can see i fetch data from my DATABASE using redux. Now i would like to refresh this component every 5 seconds so that if DATABASE changes, every 5 seconds my component refreshes and show new values

I tried playing with useEffect but i couldnt reach to get any good results. Please help me :D

Here's my useGetAllBetsQuery() code

```js
export const liveApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: "liveApi",
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({baseUrl: URL}),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getAllBets: builder.query({
            query: () => "live",
        })
    })
})

export const { useGetAllBetsQuery } = liveApi
```

Comment: is `useGetAllBetsQuery` a hook? does it export the fetchmethod as well?

Comment: so basically, you can put `useEffect` in you component, and use `setInterval` calling you fetch method. Or you should place this snippet within your `useGetAllBetQuery` hook

Comment: Im quite new to redux so i dont understand it really good... useGetAllBetQuery i think is a hook generated by redux toolkit...
Ill' modify my question to show the code

Comment: U think i can use useffect inside the reducer?

Comment: Because if i try to put my hook useGetAllBetQuery() inside a useEffect it throws me an error

Comment: Oh I see, the hook is from redux-toolkit. Then add simply polling argument. Like this

Comment: `const { data } =  useGetAllBetsQuery({pollingInterval: 5000})` as it already got this. Checkout this one https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/polling

Comment: Thank you! gonna try it!

Comment: Doesnt seem to work by only adding {pollingInterval} inside the hook :/

Comment: I dont know why but by adding pollingInterval it throws this error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map').
I think he tries to read Data when data isnt already fetched..
But its strange because without pollingInterval my app works fine

Comment: I'm not sure whether you had previously it worked -- as you'll have `{data.map((data, index)` undefined until the request is loaded anyways. you can add checking it likes this `{data && data.map(....)}` or you can add a case to render loading state if have no data

Comment: if (!data) return <div>Loading...</div>;

return <Paper>
...
</Paper>

Comment: For automatically refreshing the data ,the best way i would suggest is to implement sockets. This will allow you automatically refresh whenever the new values are added or updated.